# filter rows by minimum value relative to a factor column

Tags: r, dplyr

i need to filter a DF by the minimum value relative to a column. Example:

| RowNumber | Some_Factor | Value | One_of_many_random_columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | Hello World! |
| 2 | A | 15 | Hello World! |
| **3** | **A** | **8** | **Hello World!** |
| 4 | B | 20 | Hello Again! |
| **5** | **B** | **18** | **Hello Again!** |
| 6 | B | 25 | Hello Again! |

In this example I would like to filter rows 3 & 5. because they have the minimum `DF$Value` relative to `DF$Some_Factor`.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Some_Factor) %>%
  filter(Value == min(Value))
```

Comment: You are welcome! Consider learning more about dplyr, here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: thanks again, I'm learning it. I've been using its verbs for months now. I didn't know i could use a group and then filter it. usually i just used the group_by before a summarize.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `slice_min` after `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Some_Factor) %>% 
  slice_min(Value) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
  RowNumber Some_Factor Value One_of_many_random_columns
      <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>                     
1         3 A               8 Hello World!              
2         5 B              18 Hello Again!
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ave` in `subset`.

```
subset(dat, Some_Factor == ave(Some_Factor, RowNumber, FUN=min))
#   RowNumber Some_Factor Value One_of_many_random_columns
# 3         A           8 Hello                     World!
# 5         B          18 Hello                     Again!
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(RowNumber = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), Some_Factor = c(10L, 
15L, 8L, 20L, 18L, 25L), Value = c("Hello", "Hello", "Hello", 
"Hello", "Hello", "Hello"), One_of_many_random_columns = c("World!", 
"World!", "World!", "Again!", "Again!", "Again!")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , .SD[which.min(Value)], by = Some_factor]
```

Output:

```
   Some_factor RowNumber Value One_of_many_random_columns
1:           A         3     8               Hello World!
2:           B         5    18               Hello Again!
```

##### Data

```
df <- data.frame(RowNumber = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 Some_factor = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 Value = c(10,15,8,20,18,25),
                 One_of_many_random_columns = c("Hello World!", "Hello World!", "Hello World!", "Hello Again!", "Hello Again!", "Hello Again!"))
```